# How to post a sticky (highlighted) status to page wall programmatically?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, highlight, sticky

I can post regular status updates to my page wall with php by using curl...

```
$url = sprintf("https://graph.facebook.com/%s/feed", $pageName);
$params = array();      
$params['access_token'] = 'access token';
$params['description'] = "blah blah bla";
$params['message'] = "check my new site !";

$ch = curl_init();
$res = curlRequest($url, $params, $ch);
```

As I post new status updates, of course older ones gets pushed down. With the new timeline feature, you can "highlight" a status to keep it on top for 1 week. I am trying to figure out how to specify a post as "highlight" when I am posting it programmatically without having to actually go to the page and highlighting the status.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, sorry there isn't a way to programmatically make posts sticky. You have to do this manually.

Answer (score -3):

I'm suspecting you can transmit keyboard commands to accomplish this. . .
Figure out what keyboard commands do this operation on the page and then
transmit them during the curl session. . .

Almost anything you can do with a mouse, you can do with a keystroke.

-Let your Robot do your work for you. . .

-K

Comment: That answer is _so_ stupid, you _must_ be joking … (_please_?)